# How to work with CPU and memory intensive application in Linux?

Tags: linux, terminal, memory, command, cpu

This is the scenario,- it is a Java Application mainly, Heap Dump & Thread Dump is not helping me. Maybe I am not wise analyzing it.

Observation 1) Lots of memory seems to be utilized.

```
[maddipp1@pacoa13l ~] $ cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       65807504 kB
MemFree:         4890688 kB
```

Observation 2) CPU usage is intensive.

Excerpt from top command,-

id - Time spent in idle operations is also high in all the hosts.

```
94.8 id - pacoa12l.unix.anz
81.4 id - pacoa13l.unix.anz
98.2 id  - pacoa06l.unix.anz
```

At overall, our java-based web application sucks by consuming more time for a web page to open. I would like to know with any linux based command(s) or settings with it I can handle the situation. I cannot command on about the design patterns or the way application is designed, I am with L3 support, so I look towards the resolution, we have given certain suggestions although, but with it no improvements at all. Please guide me something considering a linux based application which runs on and consumes cpu / memory

So, how can I work with CPU and memory intensive applications in Linux ?

Comment: Regarding memory, having over 4GiB free means that the system is fine. You need to check the amount of memory that’s used, not free. Regarding CPU, if your system shows over 80% idle time then either the system has an enormous number of CPUs or your program isn’t really CPU-intensive. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: At overall, our java-based web application sucks by consuming more time for a web page to open. I would like to know with any linux based command(s) or settings with it I can handle the situation. I cannot command on about the design patterns or the way application is designed, I am with L3 support, so I look towards the resolution, we have given certain suggestions although, but with it no improvements at all. Please guide me something considering a linux based application which runs on and consumes cpu / memory

Comment: What issues are you having exactly?

Comment: renice your app and recheck

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.